# How to designate a string primary key in sqlalchemy and enter it directly?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, primary-key

My DBmodel

```
class Unix(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'unix'

    accession = Column('accession', String, primary_key=True)
    code_id = Column(BIGINT, ForeignKey('code.id'))

    code = relationship('Code', backref=backref('unix', order_by=id))

    def __init__(self, accession):
        self.accession = accession
```

and my code

```
unix = Unix(accession='asd')
unix.code(code)
self.session.add(unix)
self.session.commit()
```

But when I use that DBmodel , all other models throw an error.

```
TypeError: id() takes exactly one argument (0 given)
```

What's the reason?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it..

My DBmodel had accession, not id.

I changed order_by.

```
order_by=id -> order_by=accession
```

thank you